# Use eslint on cloud 9 ide

Tags: javascript, eslint, c9.io

I have installed eslint correctly, like the following on my cloud 9 (c9) environment:

```
npm install -g eslint 
eslint --init
```

I would like to actively use eslint with c9 on the one hand to get errors fixed, but on the other hand to point out inconsistencies within my js. However, I haven`t found any configuration page or way to add it directly to the ide.

Any suggestions how to add my configuration to c9 and run the `eslint` command automatically?

Appreciate your replies!

Comment: c9 = Cloud9 right?

Comment: @SumnerEvans Yes. Just edited my answer. Btw I haven`t found any resource that explains this issue properly. Even within their support forum.

Comment: Do you want the `eslint` command to be runned everytime you save the file,  everytime you run the file, or what? I'm sure what you mean by *automatically*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud9 has eslint built in by default, however the default implementation of eslint uses a browser copy of eslint that does not support the same features as the cli tool, This plugin supports eslint properly.

https://github.com/michaelmitchell/c9.ide.language.javascript.eslintd

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, but the linked plugin (eslintd) is no longer available. I have eslint installed on my ec2 instance and can manually run it from the command line. But I can't seem to get the lint errors to show up in the cloud9 ace editor.

I've added react-hooks rules, and I'd love for them to show up in the cloud9 editor.

Does the cloud9 linter still use a browser copy that doesn't support the same features as the cli tool? How do I get this working? I'd love any advice!